# angular ui-select not loading big list in dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ui-select, angular-ui-select

Here is my json file of the cities of the world: [google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B73smSNUQ01-NDdsd0pqY3FRODA/view?usp=sharing).

and here is my html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">
        CITY
    </label>
    <ui-select name="city" ng-model="myModel.city" theme="selectize" >
        <ui-select-match placeholder="{{ 'placeholders.project.city' | translate }}">
            {{$select.selected}}
        </ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="r in selectedcity | filter: $select.search">
            <div ng-bind-html="r | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</div>
```

why the list of some countries is not loading? is the problem with the json file? or is it because some countries have a big list of cities? is it because it surpasses the ui-select limit?
some countries load the list, and some doesn't, it is empty.

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net with your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to limit the view to a small number to have a good performance, like `| limitTo: 10`:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="r in selectedcity | filter: $select.search | limitTo: 10">
```